# allow validations only when resource added from activeadmin rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin

I have a form in `active admin` for user. I have added a validation 'presence' for the below attribute,

```
validates :needy_id, presence: true
```

I want it to work only when the request comes from `activeadmin`. 
Any suggestions?

Comment: Which users uses your `activeadmin` ?

Comment: admin only.......

Comment: How can you identify user as Admin?

Comment: I think you can keep some kind of hidden field in activeadmin form to check where the request is coming from and run your validation only if that attribute is present.

Answer (score 1):

Please check this,

`validates :needy_id, :presence => true, :if => Proc.new { user.admin? }`

Comment: This can be simplified to `validates :needy_id, presence: true, if: :admin?`